# How should I read Metadata of a response sent by gRPC server from a client in Java?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

It is so easy to send Metadata from client to server using gRPC in Java because there is an explicit parameter in a method of a service class generated by proto compiler.

I'm actually using Kotlin DSL for calling server API(But, request and response class is Java) and I can see that parameter inside of the generated Kotlin code like below.

```kotlin
suspend fun randomGrpcFunction(request: Request, headers: Metadata = Metadata()): Response =
    unaryRpc(
  channel,
  RandomGrpcClass.getRandomGrpcFunctionMethod(),
  request,
  callOptions,
  headers
)
```

On the other hand, when receiving the response sent from the server to client, I can't see any fields in response class related to Metadata. I initially thought that I can just access some member variable of the response class.

What is the simplest way to read Metadata from a gRPC client in Java?

I'm also wondering why it would be designed like this? It must be much easier if I can just read Metadata through a member variable of the response class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not very convenient in gRPC Java. You have to use an interceptor to move the desired metadata into context. See this [example of accessing response metadata](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/ccf91018285cf112c0cc287cd9f1ef6ad161717e/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/header/HeaderClientInterceptor.java#L52) in grpc-java repo.

As for the design question, this [grpc-io group discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/slslneTVjTM) seems to answer that.

Comment: Actually I've already found that solution, but I can't find the right way to pass specific header value to the call sight of the gRPC API. According to what I found so far is, the simplest way to solve it is putting the value I want to pass to gRPC Context. But, I can't find how I could pass new Context to the call sight. I'm using Kotlin Coroutine and Spring WebFlux btw.

Comment: sorry, I haven't tried this setup. Maybe post a separate question describing your setup and the problem with code samples.